# What is the Meteor way to load external JS, CSS, and update the document on loading?

Tags: jquery, dom, meteor

I hade some working HTML file using Bootstrap 3, jquery, and custom CSS. I'm trying to take that code and fit it into my Meteor application, The issue that I'm having is getting my head around how to load the CSS and HTML in a fashion that works with Meteor. For example here are some scripts that I want to load into my template.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/jquery.nouislider.all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/infobox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/richmarker-compiled.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{rooturl}}/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

I started by simply including this in the head of my template, it seems to work for the most part but I'm getting erratic behavior. Inside of custom.js I'm doing most of my setup inside the

`$(document).ready(function($) {})`

for instance setting up my time picker

```
//  Timepicker ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if( $('.oh-timepicker').length > 0 ) {
        $('.oh-timepicker').timepicker();
    }

    $('.item .quick-view').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong? what is the proper meteor way to add js and CSS in a certain order to your HTML.

Also, it seems like on one page with an Autoform, it just keeps reloading its self. I'm very confused about how to update the DOM without trigger meteor to reload the page. This is the first time I'm using Meteor and I'm thinking perhaps it was the wrong choice since I don't really need reactive templates.

Answer (score 0):

Including files like this isn't the meteor way, and that's why the behaviour is erratic.

Use this to include jquery:

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/jquery

There are other packages on atmosphere too. The order of inclusion is looked after by meteor.

Comment: how about scripts that do not have a meteor package, and what  of my own code that I want to call when the document is ready?

Comment: Meteor.startup is called on document ready or device ready. You can either place scripts in the client folder or subfolders, or have an imports folder and explicitly import those, which works for css,html and js alike